# How to delete a cell in UITableView by using custom button in cell?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have UITableView. I customized the cell height (80.0f).

I have 4 labels(UILabel) and 1 image(UIImage) and 3 buttons (UIButton). one of the button is delete button. By touching the cell or button(play button) on the image a video is loaded and played.

I need to delete the cell by touching delete button.
I wrote a selector for delete button. I can delete the video from the library. But how to delete the cell from the table ?

Thank you. 
The following image shows the delete button of my program.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c2036dee19.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c2036dee19.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution when I did this.

```
-(void)deleteClicked:(id)sender
{
    UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
    clickedButtonPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:clickedCell];

    NSArray *arrayDelete = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectoryD = [arrayDelete objectAtIndex:0]; 

    NSDictionary *dictOfplist1 = [contentArray objectAtIndex:clickedButtonPath.row];

   //To remove the videos from Documents folder       
    NSString *pathTemp1  = [documentsDirectoryD stringByAppendingString:[dictOfplist1 objectForKey:@"fileVideoE"]];
    BOOL succeed1 = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:pathTemp1 error:nil];

   //To remove the images shown in cell from Documents folder.  
    NSString *pathTemp2  = [documentsDirectoryD stringByAppendingString:[dictOfplist1 objectForKey:@"fileImageE"]];
    BOOL succeed2 = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:pathTemp2 error:nil];

   //To remove the data from the plist which is in Documents folder.
    NSString *pathDelete = [documentsDirectoryD stringByAppendingString:@"/details.plist"];
    [contentArray removeObjectAtIndex:[clickedButtonPath row]];
    [contentArray writeToFile:pathDelete atomically: YES];

    //To reload the data of the plist after deleting the items from it.
 [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Every thing was fine the cell is removed, the data in the plist is removed the videos and images in Documents folder are removed.

Here is the image when I delete the 2nd row.
Thank You.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f3c96ae3a7.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f3c96ae3a7.png)

Answer (score 3):

If your model is updated as you say, use this method on the table view to remove the cell with animation:

```
- (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths
              withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:

The table view will clean up the cell for you.

Note that the `commitEditingStyle:` method is only called when the tableview's delete button (the one you get via editing mode or swipe-to-delete) is touched. From your question it sounds like you have a custom button which is why this method is not called. You could call it yourself but I wouldn't recommend it since it should only be called by the tableview itself.

Answer (score 1):

Call:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

You need to do some research on the MVC idiom.