# UIView behind cells of a UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to insert a view behind the cells of a uitableview but I can't find a way to do it properly. Everytime I add a subview to self.view or self.tableview, it goes on the foreground, even if I use the method "sendSubviewToBack:" ...
Do someone have an idea on how to achieve it ?

PS : I don't want to use self.tableview.backgroundView because the view is fixed.

Thanks

Comment: what exactly you need to show in the view behind the table? any image as reference?

Comment: I need to show a view with images and labels.

Comment: but where? any ref image will be a plus point..like this??http://www.google.com/imgres?q=custom+cell+uitableviewcell&hl=en&biw=1280&bih=647&gbv=2&tbm=isch&tbnid=WZgQPo_srnppMM:&imgrefurl=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745045/how-to-delete-a-cell-in-uitableview-by-using-custom-button-in-cell&docid=kBguNvMao2rvXM&imgurl=http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c2036dee19.png&w=339&h=520&ei=6SUxT9WJNpGnrAfEhL2GBA&zoom=1

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/220/capturedcran20120207142.png/ I want the image to be behing the uitableview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you experience is logical. The `self.view` of a `UITableView` is indeed the table view. If you insert a subview, it is inserted on top of the table view - and there is no way to send it to the back.

**Solution 1**

The most flexible solution is to switch to a `UIViewConntroller` and implement the table view behaviour yourself. You need to

- insert your own table view as a `@property`. This is now a subview of `self.view`. You can do this in code or in IB.
- declare and implement the `<UITableViewDelegate>` and `<UITableViewDatasource>` protocols
- set the `delegate` and `datasource` properties of the table view to `self`
- insert any other subviews at will and shuffle them around as you wish.

**Solution 2**

If you just want to display something behind the tableView you might be able to use the table view property `backgroundView`. This will display behind the cells, but you will have limited control over the view's size (which you could again solve with further subviews of the background view). Also, you need to make sure your cells are transparent.

Comment: That's what I thought. The main problem with `backgroundView`is that it is static so ... I will reimplement the tableview behaviour. Thanks !

Answer (score 10):

I solved it by calling `[self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.myBackgroundView]` in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`. This will put the view behind each cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view atIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

with index 0 will take the View to position which is the back-most one.

This is a method on UIView.
Since UITableView Inherits from UIScrollView : UIView : UIResponder : NSObject. I guess this would help.